# Why does the GameObject not append to the List?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game prototype, this game would require to
 spawn  some GameObjects which I call "stars", all good with
 instantiating, but when I try to delete them when there are to many
 around it does not work, I am trying to put all instantiated
 GameObjects in a list and then delete the last object from it when
 the new one was instantiated. As you can see from the code, when 3
 objects are spawned the script should delete one from the beginning
 and spawn a new one in the same time.

Now, the problem is that I don't know what am I missing here, the code does not work and I don't know why. Please help me. Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnStar : MonoBehaviour {

    public float addedSpeed = -200f;

    private GameObject spawned;
    private float randomX;
    public GameObject starToSpawn;
    private List<GameObject> activeGO;


    void Start ()
    {
        activeGO = new List<GameObject> ();
        Invoke ("InstantiateStar", 2f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce( new Vector3( 0f, addedSpeed, 0f));
    }

    void InstantiateStar () 
    {
        randomX = Random.Range (-3f, 3f);
        GameObject GO;
        GO = Instantiate (starToSpawn, new Vector3(randomX, 5f, 0f), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        activeGO.Add (GO);
        if ( activeGO[0].transform.position.y < -2f)
        {
            DeleteActiveGO ();
        }
    }
    void DeleteActiveGO ()
    {
        Destroy (activeGO [0]);
        activeGO.RemoveAt (0);
    }
}
```

I am back with an update. The problem was that I was trying to do 2 thing in one script...short story: To solve the problem I created an empty object in the scene, divided my script in 2 separated scripts, one that makes the spawned object move faster and one that is spawning the object, I put the script that moves the object on to the object that will be spawned and The other script on the empty GameObject that will spawn the "Stars" and it worked like a charm.
Thank you for all your answers!

here are the final scripts:

> Spawning script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnStars : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] starsToSpawn;

    private List<GameObject> spawnedStars;

    private float randomX;

    void Start () 
    {
        spawnedStars = new List<GameObject> ();
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnStar", 0f, 3f);
    }
    void SpawnStar () 
    {
        randomX = Random.Range (-3, 3);
        GameObject GO;
        GO = Instantiate ( starsToSpawn[0], new Vector3 (randomX, 5f, 0f), transform.rotation);

        spawnedStars.Add (GO);

        if (spawnedStars.Count > 2 ) 
        {
            Destroy (spawnedStars [0]);
            spawnedStars.RemoveAt (0);
        }
    }
}
```

> Moving script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveStar : MonoBehaviour {

    public float acceleration = -5f;

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce( new Vector3( 0f, acceleration,0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? "Code does not work" is rather vague.

Comment: Where in the code do you check whether three objects are spawned? The only code I see will delete a star when it's y coordinate is out of range. Also, what is `starToSpawn` set to? Because it looks like your `FixedUpdate` is moving the `SpawnStar` gameobject, not the spawned stars, which means none of your stars will ever delete. Are your stars actually moving?

Comment: Yhea, I did some mistakes, the scripte is attached to the object that I want to delete...

Comment: I will devide the script into 2 separate ones and I will handle the spawning differently...thank you for pointing out the mistakes, I will edit the question and come back with the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `Invoke ("InstantiateStar", 2f);` only call once.

You can change to `InvokeRepeating("InstantiateStar",2f,2f );`

The Code  `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce( new Vector3( 0f, addedSpeed,  0f));` seem like should attach to the Generate Gameobject.

Also note your delete condition.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**@Noobie**: What you are trying to do is called **Object Pooling**. Your implementation is rather not correct.

It would be better for you to learn the same and implement.

**Read more here**: [*https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling*](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)